# AWS ALB rule for path based routing | How to add = sign to the AWS ALB condition path

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I use ALB rule path based routing, I have paths that contain = character in the URL, however AWS doesn't accept = character. For instance how to add the following paths:

https://test.example.com:8008/service.svc?channel=AXB?singleWsdl
https://test.example.com:8080/service.svc?channel=AXB

so AWS ALB path condition doesn't accept all regex, so how I can add the conditions with = character

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this URL: `"https://test.example.com:8008/service.svc?channel=AXB?singleWsdl"` the path is `/service.svc`. Everything after that (everything after the `?`) is part of the query string, not the path.

So instead of using a `path-pattern` condition, you should be using a `query-string` condition.